# PowerShell Move document with exclusions in subfolder within the Source

Tags: powershell

trying to accomplish something I thought would be straightforward
Moving the Content of a folder c:\folder into a Subfolder I create for the occasion c:\Folder\Dest

Exemple of the error

```
Line |
   5 |      Move-Item $_ -Destination $newPath -Force
     |      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Could not find a part of the path '/Users/Desktop/Source/Dest/1/1'.
Move-Item: 
Line |
   5 |      Move-Item $_ -Destination $newPath -Force
     |      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Could not find a part of the path '/Users/Desktop/Source/Dest/Dest/1/Facture1 (1).pdf'.
Move-Item: 
Line |
   5 |      Move-Item $_ -Destination $newPath -Force
     |      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Could not find a part of the path '/Users/Desktop/Source/Dest/Dest/1/Facture1 (2).pdf'.
```

```
$source = "/Users/Desktop/Source"

$dest = Join-Path   $source -ChildPath "Dest"
New-Item $dest -ItemType Directory

Get-ChildItem $source -Recurse -Exclude *.pst,'Dest' | ForEach-Object {

    $newPath = $_.FullName -replace [regex]::Escape($source),$dest

    Move-Item $_ -Destination $newPath -Force

}
```

It works for the most part but generates error
Issue is moving to a subfolder within the source, for some reason it create a loop trying to re-create the subfolder and move files again...

Answer (score 0):

You are overthinking it.

```
$FileList = Get-ChildItem $Directory
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Name $SubDirectory
$FileList | Move-Item -Destination $SubDirectory
```

Comment: Beware that the subdirectory is INSIDE the source directory. If this subdirectory already exists your code would try to move files and folders to itself. Also you don't specify `-Recurse` which is needed for files and folders within subfolders

Comment: the directory creation was part of the code used by OP, so I also using that.   
In the event the subdirectory creation is from somewhere else, just use `$FileList=Get-ChildItem | where BaseName -NotLike $SubDirectory` and skip the `New-Item`

Also my tests on 7.4 all moved everything, including subdirectories and files inside, without `-Force`

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is because the destination folder is INSIDE the source folder and your code tries to move these aswell onto the same destination location.
The `Exclude` parameter on Get-ChildItem works on the folder or file NAME only, not on the full path, so to exclude files already in the destination, you need a `Where-Object` clause

Try

```
$source = "\Users\Desktop\Source"
# create the destination folder if not already exists and take its FullName
$dest = (New-Item -Path (Join-Path -Path $source -ChildPath "Dest") -ItemType Directory -Force).FullName

Get-ChildItem -Path $source -Recurse -File -Exclude '*.pst' |
    Where-Object{ $_.DirectoryName -notlike "$dest*" } |  # exclude files that are already in the destination folder
    ForEach-Object {
        # check if this file was in a subfolder and create that in the destination if need be
        $target = Join-Path -Path $dest -ChildPath $_.DirectoryName.Substring($source.Length)
        if (!(Test-Path -Path $target -PathType Container)) {
            Write-Verbose "Creating folder '$target'"
            $null = New-Item -Path $target -ItemType Directory
        }
        Write-Verbose "Moving '$($_.FullName)' to '$target'"
        $_ | Move-Item -Destination $target -Force
    }
```